# How to display the contents of a variable in a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I passed a variable from first.m to seViewController.m. I'm able to print that variable using NSLog(@variable) but I'm unable to use textField.text=variable. How to print that variable in a textbox?

```
-(void)insert:variable  
{  
    NSLog(@"%@",variable); 

    textfield.text=variable;  
}
```

In my text box value is not coming...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
textfield.text=[variable description]; // or -localizedDescription
```

That's what is used when you print your object using NSLog.

However it may be more appropriate to get some textual attributes from your object and then assign them to textField. That will depend, of course, of what type your variable is, what info it contains and how you want to print it...

Comment: what is mean by description here?

Comment: description is a NSObject method - it gets called for example when you log your object with %@ format specifier. For custom types you normally need to implement it yourself, otherwise you'll get only object type and variable address (by default). Some standard classes implement that method to display more sensible info (e.g. UIView prints its frame and some flags)

Answer (score 1):

Try This code:

-(void)insert:(NSString*) variable
{
    NSLog(@"%@",variable);

```
textfield.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",variable];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try with below

```
-(void)insert:(NSString*) variable  
{  
    NSLog(@"%@",variable); 

    textfield.text=variable;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't indicate `variable`'s type in your code snippet (is that valid Objective-C syntax?). If it's an `NSString`, your code should work as is. If it's any object type (including `NSString`), you can use the `description` method to get a descriptive string.
If it's a C primitive (`int`, `float`, etc.) you will have to create an NSString (possibly using [`NSString stringWithFormat]`.